# How to hide and show div with button? How to add effect to the button when show the div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, show-hide, effect

I want to hide and show div with button, but when I click the button, it can only show the div, but can not hide.

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/4vaxE/24/

My coding

```
<div class="buttons" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);">
<a class="button" id="showdiv1">Div 1</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv2">Div 2</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv3">Div 3</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div id="div4">4</div>
```

CSS

```
.button {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
    clip: rect(auto,auto,auto,auto);
}

#div1 {
    background:aqua;
    padding:20px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}
#div2 {
    background:blue;
    padding:20px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}
#div3 {
    background:orange;
    padding:20px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}

#div4 {
    background:green;
    padding:20px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}
a {
    color:aqua;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1.0);
}
a:hover {
    color:red;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.0);
}
```

Javascript

```
$('#showdiv1').click(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div1').show();
});
$('#showdiv2').click(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div2').show();
});

$('#showdiv3').click(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div3').show();
});

$('#showdiv4').click(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div4').show();
});
```

beside, I want to add some effect when show the div, this is the example that I want
http://jqueryui.com/show/

How can I modify my fiddle so that when click the button, it will have some effect. I want the effect of "explode" when show the div.

How can I add in to my fiddle?

Thanks

Comment: $('div[id^=div]').hide(); line 1
    $('#div1').show();        line 2
after line 1 run, line 2 will run => that why it's always show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JS**

```
var selectedEffect="explode";
var options = { percent: 100 };
$('#showdiv1').click(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();

    $('#div1').show( selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
});
$('#showdiv2').click(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div2').show( selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
});

$('#showdiv3').click(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div3').show( selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
});

$('#showdiv4').click(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div4').show( selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
});

function callback() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $( "#effect:visible" ).removeAttr( "style" ).fadeOut();
      }, 1000 );
    };
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vaxE/28/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#div1').toggle();
```

Use toggle instead of show and hide,
for effect you can try slidetoggle or fade effect

Comment: thanks, its work, but when I click another button, the next div will add to below, the previous div does not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#showdiv1').click(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').slideUp();
    $('#div1').slideDown();
});
$('#showdiv2').click(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').slideUp();
    $('#div2').slideDown();
});

$('#showdiv3').click(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').slideUp();
    $('#div3').slideDown();
});

$('#showdiv4').click(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').slideUp();
    $('#div4').slideDown();
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/45k6g/

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$('#showdiv1').click(function () {
    if ( $('div[id^=div]').css('display') === 'block' ) {
        $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    } else {
        $('#div1').show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#showdiv1').click(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide(500);
    $('#div1').show(1000);
});
$('#showdiv2').click(function () {
   $('div[id^=div]').hide(500);
    $('#div2').show(1000);
});

$('#showdiv3').click(function () {
   $('div[id^=div]').hide(500);
    $('#div3').show(1000);
});

$('#showdiv4').click(function () {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide(500);
    $('#div4').show(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div1').show();
```

by this

```
  if($('#div1').css('display')=='none'){
     $('#div1').show();
    }else {
    $('#div1').hide();
    }
```

Comment: I checked in your jsfiddle, i worked well, that code just for div1, do you want to hide 2 3 4 if 1 is showed, right?

Answer (score 0):

Not as familiar with jquery Explode I looked up the doc, just to see what it had to say: http://api.jqueryui.com/explode-effect/, after a quick read I jumped on your fiddle.

Just looking at the fiddle I saw a couple of things. First of all you needed to reference jquery UI. http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js

So in fiddle go to external resources and add that url. Once you have done that pick which box you want to explode by doing the following with your code:

```
$('#showdiv1').click(function () {
$('div[id^=div]').hide();
$( "#div1" ).toggle( "explode" ); });
```

I tested it and it worked for me. Good luck, and keep trying.. You were really close!

Comment: thanks, it works~! but this is not the explode effect I want.
I will read the link you provided, thanks~